# How can I sync Opera Mail contacts automaticly?

Tags: email, sync, opera, contacts

I use Opera Mail as my default e-mail client and I'd like to synchronise the contacts between computers. I can do it per request by exporting and importing the contacts, but I don’t want to this every time I add a new contact.

How can I synchronise Opera Mail contacts automatically between numerous computers?

Answer (score 0):

Opera Mail stores the contacts in a file called `contacts.adr` in the location `“%appdata%/Opera Mail/Opera Mail”`. One must synchronise this file between the computers. To do this, you can use many programs, like OneDrive, DropBox or NextCloud.

In many cases you can synchronise only complete folders, but you only want to sync one single file. You can move this file from this folder to another one, for example, to `%USERPROFILE%/Contacts/Opera`, and synchronise only that folder. But then you also must tell Opera Mail where to find this file.

Unfortunately, it is not well documented, how to tell opera where the contacts file is located. Edit the configuration file of Opera Mail called operaprefs.ini located next to the original contacts.adr, and add the following lines:

```
[MailBox]
AddressFile=%USERPROFILE%/Contacts/Opera/SyncedContacts.adr
```

After this, Opera will load and save all contacts to the file `SyncedContacts.adr` located in `%USERPROFILE%/Contacts/Opera/`. Copy the content of your `contacts.adr` file in case of necessity. Set up Opera Mail on the other computers too. Set up the synchronisation of the folder `%USERPROFILE%/Contacts/Opera` between computers with NextCloud. (With DropBox, you may need to save the file in a special folder for DropBox.)

This solution also works in Linux if you use the browser Opera not newer than version 12.